# ADB: Libraries to simulate bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

I want to simulate a Bluetooth headset being connected to a phone, to see how my code reacts to the intents and the connection as a whole. I'm testing on a real device connected via USB, in Eclipse.

I have been able to simulate the pressing of a "media button" by running the following:

```
adb shell input keyevent <keycode>
```

I was hoping for something similar, where I can set the device name, device class etc and trigger it?

Running the following produces instructions on various calls that can be made to adb:

```
adb shell am start
```

The way to trigger an intent "ACL_CONNECTED" is by typing this:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_CONNECTED
```

further options can be added in the command, as per the instructions from above.

The problem is, I want to simulate all the functionality of a Bluetooth device, not just the few intents it triggers. In other words, I want a dummy Bluetooth device which is indistinguishable from a real device from the phone's point of view.

Comment: Can you specify what functionality you want to simulate? A [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) "is really just a thin wrapper for a Bluetooth hardware address".